# Visual Studio 2010 and Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have Sharepoint 2007, and I am going to buy Visual Studio for the first time.
Does Visual Studio 2010 work with Sharepoint 2007?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2009/02/19/sharepoint-tools-support-in-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VisualStudio/Sharepoint-Development-with-Visual-Studio-2010/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it does. But be aware of the different versions of Visual Studio.

VS 2010 you can build workflows, list definitions, site definitions, web parts, etc. etc.

Comment: what do u mean by your warning, isn't 2010 a version of VS?

Comment: There are different "levels" for instance standard, professional, team systems, etc, etc.  Also 2010 isn't coming out till march of next year iirc.

Comment: i see, thx....they do have a beta version for 2010, as a new VS person, would that be ok for my purposes (learning .NET/C# and Sharepoint 2007)?

Comment: As said by envalid. You have different versions. check the msdn site for VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can't buy Visual Studio 2010 yet.  It's not due to be released until this spring.